# How does `Borrow` work without trait specialization?

Tags: rust, traits

Currently, Rust does not have the feature "trait specialization" yet. As far as I understand, this means that a trait can't be implemented more than once for one given type. However, I noticed that the [`Borrow` trait](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/trait.Borrow.html) is implemented `for T where T: ?Sized` which are all non-reference types there are (right?). But it's also implemented for several other types, like `Vec<T>`, which looks like a specialization.

How is that working? Is it compiler magic or did I misunderstand what trait specialization is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Short answer

In this case, trait specialization is not necessary, since the implementations are non-overlapping.

## Long answer

In the particular case of `Vec<T>`, there are many impls that apply to it. For instance, the following:

```
impl<T> Borrow<T> for T where T: ?Sized
impl<'a, T> Borrow<T> for &'a T where T: ?Sized
impl<'a, T> Borrow<T> for &'a mut T where T: ?Sized
// other implementations are omitted for conciseness
```

According to those implementations, the compiler can deduce the following:

1. `Vec<T>` implements `Borrow<Vec<T>>`
2. `&'a Vec<T>` implements `Borrow<Vec<T>>`
3. `&'a mut Vec<T>` implements `Borrow<Vec<T>>`

However, none of them implements `Borrow<[T]>` for `Vec<T>`. Since that implementation is not provided, you are free to provide your own:

```
impl<T> Borrow<[T]> for Vec<T>
```